# Javascript equation with negative and positive numbers

Tags: javascript, equation

I have four text input fields, after the user enters relevant values, I have to make a JavaScript calculation to add all of them

I use:

```
 var total = Number(value1) + Number(value2) + Number(value3) + Number(value4);
```

then I display the total:

```
document.getElementById("value5").innerHTML = total;
```

If one of the values is negative, it gets added as a positive number. How do I get the equation to treat it as a negative one (so it gets subtracted)?

Comment: No, it doesn't, and [here's proof](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhB8y/).

Comment: Basic math? `5 + (-3) = 5 - 3`. All programming languages I know obey that rule (it would be very weird otherwise).

Comment: Post ur entire code, probably ur doing a mistake somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what the problem is but it works well

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
 function fnc(){
 val1=Number(document.getElementById("t1").value);
  val2=Number(document.getElementById("t2").value);

 var total = val1+val2;
 document.getElementById("t3").value=total;
 }
 </script>
 input1: <input type="text" id="t1" />
  input2: <input type="text" id="t2" />
  <br />
<input type="text" id="t3" />
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="fnc()" value="click me" />
```